# How can I reshape image data?

Tags: python, image, resize, reshape

I'm trying to reshape an image into the size I want. There is an image dataset I got online and the shape of each image in the dataset is `(3, 128, 128)`.

I want the shape of each image to be `(128, 128, 3)`. I know that there are several functions in python for reshaping (np.reshape) and resizing (skimage.transform.resize), but I'm not sure if these functions are the right functions for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

An appropriate function for this situation is `numpy.transpose()`. Assuming you have an `image` of shape `(3, 128, 128)`, you can reshape it into your desired dimensions `(128, 128, 3)` like so:

```
reshaped_image = np.transpose(image, axes=(1, 2, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I never thought about using transpose... Thanks so much again